# Hyperactive kitten after neuter surgery?

Tags: cats, neutering, surgery

I took my kitten in to get neutered yesterday and when I picked him up he was obviously out of it, but still pretty aware of his surroundings. The vet tech gave us a rundown of what to expect and I feel at ease.

On the drive home he peed in his carrier, which I wasn’t expecting, but there was a pee of so I assume the vets were expecting.

When we got him home he looked to be back to normal with a little wobble in his walk and slight glassy eyes, but this was unexpected as the vet told us he would be “lethargic” and “in need of rest”. The vet also said that kittens rarely bother their wounds, so not to worry about a cone, but this was not the case with our Isaac. He immediately went to lick his wound. I have a cone from amazon that I had prepared. He had it off in under 5 minutes. He is very stubborn about his cone.

The vet was also insistent on keeping him from jumping, running and playing. Of course, once again, that is ALL HE WANTS TO DO. No joke, he was rolling around, hunting little spots on the wall, bitting up his bed. I have never seen him like this before. To keep an eye on him I had to run out and get a crate.

It is the next morning and I woke up to him without his cone again, licking his wound and jumping around his cage.

I want to know is this normal and above all, will he be ok? Will his wound be ok if he is so hyperactive? I’m very worried about him. It seems like he wants to do everything that the vet said to prevent him from doing or wouldn’t even be a problem.

Comment: Call your vet and describe the behaviour, they can give you advice.

Comment: A friend of mine occasionally fosters kittens; I've gone with her to pick up litters after neuter/spay surgeries. They always tell her to keep them quiet after the surgery. She always laughs. Being active any time (including after surgery) is normal for kittens and I've never used a cone on a neuter, but keep in touch with your vet and keep an eye on the incision.

Comment: It's entirely normal. You can try putting the cone back on him—he'll either shed it again nearly instantly, or not, and if not, it will keep him from licking so much. The licking itself *probably* won't damage anything: the point of the cone is to reduce the chance of infection etc. As for the hyperactivity, some cats react weirdly to anesthesia and get more active, and some react weirdly and get less active. No kitten ever reacts normally: that would be totally abnormal. :-)